# How can i set dates according to week days

Tags: php

This is my html code

```
<div class="col-md-12 left-top-content">
    <p id="day-link">
        <span><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/diet_plan/Sunday" <?= ($this->uri->segment(3) === 'Sunday')? 'class="active"':''?>>Sunday</a></span>
        <span><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/diet_plan/Monday" <?= ($this->uri->segment(3) === 'Monday')? 'class="active"':''?>>Monday</a></span>
        <span><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/diet_plan/Tuesday" <?= ($this->uri->segment(3) === 'Tuesday')? 'class="active"':''?>>Tuesday</a></span>
        <span><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/diet_plan/Wednesday" <?= ($this->uri->segment(3) === 'Wednesday')? 'class="active"':''?>>Wednesday</a></span>
        <span><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/diet_plan/Thursday" <?= ($this->uri->segment(3) === 'Thursday')? 'class="active"':''?>>Thursday</a></span>
        <span><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/diet_plan/Friday" <?= ($this->uri->segment(3) === 'Friday')? 'class="active"':''?>>Friday</a></span>
        <span><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/diet_plan/Saturday" <?= ($this->uri->segment(3) === 'Saturday')? 'class="active"':''?>>Saturday</a></span>
    </p>
```

Suppose today is "Thursday" and i m clicking on Thursday link so date is showing today date but when i clicked on another days like Saturday then link showing on Saturday but date not changed dynamically means on Saturday there is 9 sep and when i click on Monday then i want to show 4rth sep.

Check below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oRbi.png)

Comment: for this you can use fullcalendar a jquery plugin for calendar interface instead of going for manual work

Comment: The code does not include the part, where you write/change that date, you were refering to. This is only the link part.

Comment: see my answer @abhishek jain

Answer (score 0):

Try this Hope it helps try to pass the date in get parameter and after that you can get from $_GET

```
<?php $currentdate = date('Y-m-d');
    $ts = strtotime($currentdate);
    $year = date('o', $ts);
    $week = date('W', $ts);
    $days = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    foreach ($days as $key => $day) {
        $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$key);?>
        <span><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/diet_plan/<?php echo $day ?>?date="<?php echo date("Y-m-d l", $ts)?> <?= ($this->uri->segment(3) === $day)? 'class="active"':''?>> <?php echo $day ?></a></span>
    <?php } ?>
```

Hope it helps :)